# Batch Script to Copy Content from one file to another depending on search criteria

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, batch-file

I am trying to run this a process which looks into a Test.bat file with the following information:

```
object1.dir.file=c:\resources\open
object1.grp.dir=\\\drive\config\code
object1.grp.share=\\\drive\config\code
object2.grp.file=\\\drive\config\code
object2.grp.dir=\\\drive\config\code
object3.grp.file=\\\drive\config\code
```

The output I am trying to achieve is to write another .bat/Shell script to get output as 3 files:

File 1: **object1.bat**

```
object1.dir.file=c:\resources\open
object1.grp.dir=\\\drive\config\code
object1.grp.share=\\\drive\config\code
```

File 2: **object2.bat**

```
object2.dir.file=c:\resources\open
object2.grp.dir=\\\drive\config\code
```

File 3: **object3.bat**

```
object3.dir.file=c:\resources\open
```

Can anyone tell me what is the best way to achieve this without using any 3rd party tools in **windows**

Comment: I would complete this using `Get-Content`, `Where-Object` and the `-matches` operator, piped to a `ForEach-Object` loop where I would use the automatic `$Matches` variable to determine the file name, and `Add-Content` to write to the file.

Comment: In other words, do you want to _"Read the lines in Test.bat file and output they to the file indicated by the first dot-separated token and .bat extension, but replacing the first line in each subsequent file by the first line of the first file"_? This can be done in a very simple way in a .BATch file via a `for /F "tokens=1* delims=." %%a in (Test.bat) do echo %%a.%%b>> %%a.bat` command; you just need to add the testing of the first line in each file to this code...

Comment: Please explain how the output is derived from the input. The first line of each of your output files is the same, other than the starting `object`number. This may be the first line of your input data with the prefix modified. The remaining lines appear to be copied directly from their `object`number, dropping the first one. Or perhaps your obfuscating is incomplete. Do you really just want the data to be split into files depending on `object`number?

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you really want according to posted input and output data.

[Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) posted already the **FOR** loop which can be used for a simple split into several batch files.

Here is an enhanced commented version with some additional checks which can be named `Test.bat` to run on itself.

```
@echo off
if not exist Test.bat goto :EOF

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Delete all existing object*.bat files in current directory.

if exist object*.bat del /A /F /Q object*.bat

rem Process the lines of the batch file and split each line
rem into two strings on first point found in each line.
rem If the first string starts case-insensitive with word "object"
rem and there is also a second string, output the line into a file
rem with name of first string and with .bat as file extension.

for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=." %%A in (Test.bat) do (
    set "LineBegin=%%A"
    if /I "!LineBegin:~0,6!" == "object" (
        if not "%%B" == "" echo %%A.%%B>>%%A.bat
    )
)
endlocal
goto :EOF

rem Lines to write into several object*.bat files.

object1.dir.file=c:\resources\open
object1.grp.dir=\\\drive\config\code
object1.grp.share=\\\drive\config\code
object2.grp.file=\\\drive\config\code
object2.grp.dir=\\\drive\config\code
object3.grp.file=\\\drive\config\code
```

The created batch files contain:

**object1.bat:**

```
object1.dir.file=c:\resources\open
object1.grp.dir=\\\drive\config\code
object1.grp.share=\\\drive\config\code
```

**object2.bat:**

```
object2.grp.file=\\\drive\config\code
object2.grp.dir=\\\drive\config\code
```

**object3.bat:**

```
object3.grp.file=\\\drive\config\code
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`